# Viewing/Dumping Encrypt Android SMS Database

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

I wanted to debug some SMS issues for a project, and wanted to see the SMS data in my phone.  So first, I pulled out the data.

`adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db ~/Downloads/mmssms.db`

So I tried with the [SQLite Database Browser 20.b1](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) on my Mac (OS X 10.6.8), but when I open the file I see nada.  Then I tried `sqlite3`, and I still see nothing but get a little reminder of how much an idiot I am.

```
mbp62:~ sillyusernamehere$ sqlite3 ~/Downloads/mmssms.db 
SQLite version 3.6.12
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .tables
Error: file is encrypted or is not a database
sqlite>
```

So is it possible to decrypt the database at all?  Google-fu has not divined to me much info on the mechanism or how to do this off the phone.

Answer (score 3):

The database is not encrypted. You are using a database version unsupported by the SQLite Database Browser 20.b1 program.

Easy solution:

1. Download the SQLite dll file from http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html
2. Download the SQLite Administrator from http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/
3. Extract SQLite Administrator and replace the bundled sqlite3.dll with the latest version downloaded from sqlite.org
4. Run the SQLite Administrator program.
5. Open your android database.
6. Done.

--- Further Information --

The android database can opened using the sqlite windows binary, which is a shell program.

sample commands from windows cmd prompt:

```
    c:> c:\sqlite3.exe c:\mmssms.db
    sqlite> .tables
```

tables get listed out

```
    sqlite> .mode column
    sqlite> select * from sms
```

sms table gets listed out in column view

```
    ctrl-c
```

program exits

refer to the sqlite documentation to get data dumps.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial on how to change your hostname in android for wifi networks. In this tutorial I explained how to use sqlite3.

I do not believe your "mmssms.db" should be encrypted. I've looked at other databases on my Android phone as well and they were not encrypted.

View here:

http://blog.burrowsapps.com/2011/09/android-change-hostname.html?q=hostname

```
file settings.db
sqlite3 settings.db
sqlite> .databases
sqlite> .tables
sqlite> .schema secure
sqlite> select * from secure where _id = "24";
sqlite> select * from secure where name = "android_id";
sqlite> select * from secure where value = "";
sqlite> update secure set value = 0 where _id = 24;
sqlite> .exit
```

How to View (more examples):

http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-448361.html

http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-1453840.html

Please let me know if this helps! Also, can you tell me your phone and other info to help generate a more robust answer.

Is it possible you corrupted the file?

Comment: The OP clearly tried the steps until `.tables` and got an error. This does not answer or shed any light to his/her question...